# Using a dictionary to replace strings not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, replace

I am trying to use the following code to make replacements in a pandas dataframe however:

```
replacerscompanya = {',':'','.':'','-':'','ltd':'limited','&':'and'} 
df1['CompanyA'] = df1['CompanyA'].replace(replacerscompanya)

replacersaddress1a = {',':'','.':'','-':'','ltd':'limited','&':'and', r'\brd\b':'road'} 
df1['Address1A'] = df1['Address1A'].replace(replacersaddress1a)

replacersaddress2a = {',':'','.':'','-':'','ltd':'limited','&':'and', r'\brd\b':'road'} 
df1['Address2A'] = df1['Address2A'].replace(replacersaddress2a)
```

It does not give me an error but when i check the dataframe, no replacements have been made.

I had previously just used a number of lines of the code below to acheive the same result but I was hoping to create something a bit simpler to adjust.

```
df1['CompanyA'] = df1['CompanyA'].str.replace('.','')
```

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: kindly share sample data with output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape `.` in dictionary because special regex character and add parameter `regex=True` for substring replacement and also for replace by regex:

```
replacersaddress1a = {',':'','\.':'','-':'','ltd':'limited','&':'and', r'\brd\b':'road'} 
df1['CompanyA'] = df1['CompanyA'].replace(replacerscompanya, regex=True)
```

Comment: Amazing, thats worked a treat! Just for my reference what does regex=True do that helps me out here?

Comment: @ManeshHalai - because if no `regex=True` it replace only separate values like `,` to `''`, for replace in substrings like `,ss` to `ss` need `regex=True`

Comment: Got it. Thanks a bunch!